# How to sum by year using NumPy on Python

Tags: python, numpy

If I have data like this:

```
2012 $20,000
2012 $20,000
2013 $10,000
2014 $10,000
2014 $10,000
```

How do I display a data array that is [40000, 10000, 20000] where the data will be aggregated by year?

`[40000, 10000, 20000]`

Comment: what's format is your original data in?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in this format..!

```
    year    income
0   2012    $20,000
1   2012    $20,000
2   2013    $10,000
3   2014    $10,000
4   2014    $10,000
```

**Code:-**

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_csv('/content/Untitled spreadsheet - Sheet1.csv')
df1['income'] = df1['income'].replace({'\$': '', ',': ''}, regex=True)
df1['income'] = df1['income'].astype(int)
df2=df1.groupby(df1['year']).sum()
print(df2) 
lis=[]
for aggregate in df2['income']:
  lis.append(aggregate)
print(lis)
```

**Output:-**

`print(df2)`

```
       income
year        
2012   40000
2013   10000
2014   20000
```

`print(lis)`

```
[40000, 10000, 20000]
```